# How to add action listener in JMenuItem that is added to JMenu dynamically

Tags: java

In JMenuBar there are many JMenu, one of them is 'Tables'. In this JMenu I added many JMenuItem's from database, but i don't know how can i add action listener to them. Can anyone tell how?

Comment: Please tell us what you have done to try and figure this out as part of your post.

Comment: I work on a project and that project has many tables, to display them i added many JMenuItem's i.e. table names. By clicking on table name in JMenuItem that table should be display in JPanel. So for this action listener on each JMenuItem is required. So how can i add action listener to each JMENUITEM (Table names) to display them .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are adding everything dynamically but in this case you should be able to add an ActionListener to every object into whatever looping code you're facing. I will put here below and example of a for loop passing through a List of JMenuItems.

```
for(int i = 0; i < menuItemsList.size(); i++){
   JMenuItem item = menuItemList.get(i);
   item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
           //the code you want to execute in the event
       }
   });
}
```

In this case every JMenuItem will have an event.

Hope this can help, I can't do to much if you do not put an example of your code.

Regards.

Comment: But all the MenuItems has same implementation. According to this code. How to give different implementation on each MenuItems

Comment: Well in this case I recommend you to use a design pattern to instantiate dynamically every JTable, maybe you can pass as a parameter a key value for every JTable, and may use an Abstract Factory pattern to do what you want, I'm also confused, do you have idea of how many JTables are you going to show or those JTables are also added dynamically?.